# Serial comm with PHP on Windows

Tags: php, serial-port, communication

I am looking for a way to communicate with RS232 serial COM port on windows. I have found 2 solutions on the net, [one](http://www.easyvitools.com/phpserial/index.html) which is not totally free (introduces deliberate delays on the function) and [another](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3679.html) with limited capability on Windows. The latter can only write to a COM port on Windows, not read.

I can't look at the code of the first solution since it is compiled into a .dll (makes sense, otherwise people can just edit the delay and not purchase it...) and the second one seems only to use fopen() to open the port and later fwrite() to it for writing, just like one would do to a stream. But apparently freading it returns nothing.

I know it's possible as the first solution did it, although it does require Apache to use php-cgi module instead of php5module.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you positive fread() returns nothing?  On Windows, the COM ports are just specially named files, IIRC.  Perhaps you need to set up the port parameters such as parity, baud, etc, which may be impossible through PHP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every solution above is either inefficient or too much work.

You can just use the [PHP-DIO library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php) (dio_fcntl, dio_open, dio_read, dio_write, dio_seek, ...). It's also in [the PHP manual's entry for DIO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php):

This PECL package isn't available by default. To get it for Windows if you have PHP 5.2.x greater than 5.2.6, you can download it as part of a ZIP:

- [Thread-safe (for Apache)](http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip)
- [Non-thread-safe (for IIS)](http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.6-nts-Win32.zip)

Both of these links were found in http://www.deveblog.com/index.php/download-pecl-extensions-for-windows/

[Here is the build from Linux](http://pecl.php.net/package/dio), just get it and do the phpize/configure/make/make install thing.

I don't know whether it should be used in an Apache session, but go for it.

Comment: Oh my, where were you when I asked this years ago! Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set up the com port using a DOS-like command.

For example, the following line executes the command through php:

```
$output = `mode COM1: BAUD=115200 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on`;
```

To display the results you can use:

```
echo "$output";
```

Create the resource id:

```
$fp = fopen('COM1', 'r+');

if (!$fp)
{
      echo "Port not accessible";
}
else
{
     echo "Port COM1 opened successfully";
}
```

Write to port:

```
$writtenBytes = fputs($fp, "Hello");

echo"Bytes written to port: $writtenBytes";
```

Read from port:

```
$buffer = fgets($fp);

echo "Read from buffer: $buffer";
```

Maybe someone can help me with the `fgets` problem. It stacks there for exactly one minute if `TO=on`, or stacks there forever if `TO=off`. It seems to be a "`MODE COM`" option so maybe a DOS expert can help.

Perhaps instead of `fgets`, one should use `fgetc`, since `fgets` capture through to the `newline`, while `fgetc` captures a single character. If a new line isn't encountered, it may block until there is one or until the buffer is flushed. The one minute delay may be windows flushing its buffer on an interval.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to tackle this would be to write a program in another language (such as C++) and then execute it from your php script with `system()`.  Doing Comm I/O in C++ is trivial.

This assumes you have enough access to the server to configure it to allow the executable to be run by php, etc.

Comment: I'd recommend you develop your comm program as a PHP library so that it integrates directly with your PHP code.  Using system() to call and external executable is a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: Agreed, but to me that no longer falls under "the easiest way" and becomes "the best way". :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way would be to use the Win32 API through something like [`w32api_register_function()`](http://www.php.net/w32api_register_function) or [ffi](http://pecl.php.net/package/ffi) and then use [serial communications calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx) to get it to work under Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and already considered writing my own php extension when I came across this solution which is popular with Arduino developers - 'serproxy' (found it at many places, ie. http://www.lspace.nildram.co.uk/freeware.html ) sets up a tcp stack to/from the serial ports and allowed me to use the php socket functions to communicate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an object via ActiveX on windows.  There are several, mostly commercial serial objects for COM on windows.  You can also expose a .Net based object and register it for COM use as well.  Of course, this does presume you have control on the server to register a COM control, as you would need a serial interface.

Another issue is resource contention if this is for use via the Web.  If this is for a serial printer, for instance, then a print queue manager would be your best option over direct communication.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with sms using com port then here is the most famous [php serial communication class by Rémy Sanchez](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html) with [google sample code](https://code.google.com/p/php-serial/). [Here is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902831/execute-at-commands-to-send-sms-in-php) which includes that topic.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is to read the port. And it doesn't matter which method it is done, stream_get_line(), fgets() or dio_read() - they all work great.

Actually the problem is that at this point the code "hangs forever" or "hangs for a minute" depending on "xon" or "to".

According to several experiments, this happens when there is no data, as the usual terminal php does not work, and if there is no incoming data, it freezes on reading.

This can be avoided, as in the example above, after sending data to the port, execute sleep(time) to wait until the data to be read is definitely there, in which case it will be read and returned without any delay.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution of David Refoua and Giorgos Pap with some modifications to connect with Arduino UNO. In the PC side, I have an AJAX to receive the measurements from Arduino  and show them in a form. Now I am trying to update, programmatically, the COM port (in this case, COM3),

```
<?php
$output = exec("mode COM2: BAUD=115200 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on dtr=off odsr=off octs=off rts=on idsr=off");
$fp = fopen("COM2", "r+");
if (!$fp)
{
  exit("Unable to establish a connection");
}
// RX form PC**************
$t = $_POST['text1'];
// TX to Arduino****************
$writtenBytes = fputs($fp, $t);
sleep(1); 
// RX from Arduino**************
$j=0;
$dataset1 = [];
while(!$buffer=stream_get_line($fp,400,"\n")) { 1; }
// TX to PC***************
$piecesa = explode(",", $buffer);
foreach ($piecesa as $value) {  
    $dataset1[$j] = $value;
    $j++;
}
$myJSON = json_encode($dataset1);
echo $myJSON;
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The program is working very well with a short delay, around 8 sec. maximum. This is Windows OS.