# Execute AT commands to send sms in php

Tags: php, sms, at-command

I am trying to execute AT commands from PHP.

I tried exec() and shell_exec()

Please don't suggest third party SMS gateway my client doesn't want to disclose his private information and wants to send SMS from his own server.

I have a GSM modem attach to a serial port which I can access through "putty" like in fig
[image: putty screen 1]

And I can enter AT commands to send SMS like in fig below.
[image]

I want to run those AT commands through PHP.

Comment: have you tried `plink.exe`?

Comment: Can you telnet into the GSM modem? If so you could try to use fsockopen from PHP.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php
And then use fwrite to write to the socket.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes I guess here is url of what i am using http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
but I want to execute AT commands through PHP, commands on black screen on second fig

Comment: According to [this 10 year old comment on the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php#20935) you can just write to the com port with `fopen`.

Comment: WOW ! 10 year old comment, I will try that !

Comment: gave me error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi I am sending sms using php class on windows 8 by this php code.

```
require "php_serial.class.php";
$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("COM4");
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\n\r"); 
$serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgs=\"+92234444444\"\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage("sms text\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage(chr(26));

//wait for modem to send message
sleep(7);
$read=$serial->readPort();
$serial->deviceClose();
```

[PHP SERIAL class Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NgcxAkZSCHS2MzUEtQMWZYWUc0QmF0RzNBMUItck8wZUtR/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: hi @xam
can you please also add link or code for 
php_serial.class.php file

Comment: hi @MilindMore i have generated the link from google drive it's for php_serial.class.php file.
[link for php_serial.class.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NgcxAkZSCHS2MzUEtQMWZYWUc0QmF0RzNBMUItck8wZUtR/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: is this working with USB Modem?
I got an error " Specified serial port is not valid"

Comment: @IvorySantos i have not tried but  if your USB modem is appearing in Device Manager in Under "Ports (COM & LPT)" section then it should work

Comment: @xam yup it appeared on "Ports (COM & LPT)". I'm stuck on this :(

Comment: This is great man! i am using this to my project now. thanks xam!

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano nice to hear :) also upvote if it's worked

Comment: Hi Xam, i'd like to know, why the sleep is 7seconds there? I'm just curious.

Comment: Hi Xam, how to read message? i cannot do with this 
$serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgr=\"1\"\n\r");

Comment: I am able to process the send function and it says 1 if i echo the serialflush() but still not able to send msg. I am using the same code as above. It is showing the blank page

Comment: @Vivek try altering the sleep function maybe increase it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a RS232 communication class such as this one
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html

Alternatively you can also use fopen()

```
exec('mode COM1: baud=115200 data=8 stop=1 parity=n xon=on');
$fd = fopen('COM1:', O_RDWR);
fwrite($fd,chr(0).chr(1));
fclose($fd);
```

Comment: I think your suggestion will be help the one you gave with  phpclasses, please check and tell am i Doing it right here is code `$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGS='8149823689' ".chr(13)." hello world");`

Comment: I have not tried the library so I can't confirm you are doing it right ;)

Comment: BTW: if your server is running on Windows, I'm not sure serial communications with PHP will be fully working without using an external application/library