# PHP windows read write to/from serial port usind DOTNET System.IO.Ports

Tags: php, windows, serial-port

I try to capture data from a industrial scale weight serial port connection in my PHP webpage and print ticket.
Also I need to forward data to another serial port for display propose. 
I explore anything from here and Google ...except very expensive ActiveXperts Serial Port SDK I cannot find anything more complex than PHP native fopen.

I found this here, but nothing happend...no error trigger nothing

```
$serial = new DOTNET('System', 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort');
$serial->PortName = 'COM1';
$serial->Open();
```

Please give me a clue about how to implement this.

Comment: `Serproxy` (http://www.lspace.nildram.co.uk/freeware.html) could help you

Comment: I don't need network access - only windows.Thank you.

Comment: just for clarification... this is a proxy. It opens a `local` port and you can send/receive data through it with serial port.

Comment: I don't have a clue of how to use it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serial comm with PHP on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627965/serial-comm-with-php-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$serial = new DOTNET('System', 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort');
$serial->PortName = 'COM1';
$serial->Open();
```

and then and

```
$serial->Write();
$serial->Read();
```

If there is no error is worth a try. You can also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx
Also you usually end up with that info if you are searching for windows com# communication with php. Check out:
https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FXowap%2FPHP-Serial&ei=JXdSVKPsHYmGyQSftIL4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGxbGUeLotG_DvmUzDo2yBScDAqTw&sig2=AUp7IvRqKXesVZIF6Xf6MA
Its native php that suppossedly works in windows no complicated stuff and reconfigs needed