# running PHP as a service that listen to serial ports

Tags: php, tsr

(how) Can I execute a PHP code, that will stay a live and listen to a serial port?

Currently I use python and other stand-alone environments.

Please note: my problem is not reading the port, but keeping the connection a live

Comment: I don't think PHP is designed for this kind of use.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job.

Comment: try ruby, python, bash scripting.

Comment: maybe useful: [627965/serial-comm-with-php-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627965/serial-comm-with-php-on-windows). Some of the suggested libraries work on linux as well eg: [3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html).

Comment: Not sure if you are aware that PHP can be run from the shell (]CLI). [Using PHP from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only read about it a long time ago, but this should do what you want to: http://pecl.php.net/package/dio