# Reading Serial Port from PHP page on Windows 7

Tags: php, input, arduino

I have made a PHP project. The server and Client are the same computers. Arduino is connected to this computer on a USB Port. 
I need to read from Arduino and use to store in a database.

I did a lot of research but all in vain. Simple code is requested for PHP, JS, and Sketch of Arduino.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serial comm with PHP on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627965/serial-comm-with-php-on-windows)

Comment: I already tried that link but did not help me much solve my issue. If you could please help.

Comment: I Tried and Tried and tried and Tried and Tried ........Triedn times. But All methods don't work a bit. The php_DIO.dll is not getting loaded. Win32 Api doesn' work. Any ready made code will be great help. Thank you,